# Emitir mensagem PHP na mesma página HTML

Tags: php, html

Estou desenvolvendo uma página de cadastros e estou validando-a com PHP. Gostaria de notificar o usuário na mesma página de cadastro quando há algum erro.

Segue abaixo o código do formulário (tem um `session.start()` no arquivo):

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="validacao.php">
    <center>
        <input type="text" name="nome" value="" maxlength="9" class="estilo_form" placeholder="Nome"/>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" value="" maxlength="9" class="estilo_form" placeholder="Usuário"/>     
        <input type="password" name="senha" value="" maxlength="9" class="estilo_form" placeholder="Senha"/>
        <input type="password" name="senhaagain" value="" maxlength="9" class="estilo_form" placeholder="Digite novamente a Senha"/>
    </center>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="concordar" value="S" class="input_check"/>
    <font style="float:left;"/> Li e Concordo com os <a href="" class="estilo_link">Termos de uso</a>. </font>
    <a href="inicio.html"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" class="botao2">
    </a>
</form>
```

Arquivo PHP:

```
<html>
    <?php session_start(); ?>
        <body>
            <?php 
            $all = $_POST;
            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
            $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
            $senha = $_POST['senha'];
            $senha_again = $_POST['senhaagain'];
            $_SESSION['validador'] = ;

            if ( !isset( $all ) || empty( $all ) ) {
            $_SESSION['validador'] = 1; //Validador para por um echo na pagina de cadastro, juntamente com um if.
            }
            ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creio que seja apenas fazer um IF no local que vc quer: `<? if(condição){ echo "algo deu errado"; ?>`.

Comment: Já consegui fazer o que queria, obrigado gente.

Answer (score 1):

Até onde eu sei você pode usar dois tipos de validação, a back-end, no seu caso com o PHP, e a front-end (Com o JavaScript), normalmente usa-se as duas já que as validações front-end pode ser desativada pelo usuário,com o php o que vc pode fazer, criar uma sessão assim que o usuário acessar a página, segue exemplo

formulario.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$mensagem = $_SESSION['mensagem'];

if ($mensagem != "") {
    echo $mensagem;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="cadastro.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

cadastro.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$nome = $_POST['nome'];

if(empty($_POST['nome'])){
    $_SESSION['mensagem'] = "O nome não pode ficar vazio";
    header("location: formulario.php");
}else{
    #...
}
?>
```

Comment: Entendi amigo. Porém, o programa está burlando minhas condições e a mensagem está aparecendo antes mesmo de se enviar o formulário. Teria algo haver com `unset()`? Já tentei por isset(_POST['submit']) na condição e não adiantou nada. Desde já, obrigado.